# Preventing an item list from getting destroyed upon scroll down

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I'm working in a mobile app for iPad in Flex 4, I have a list with custom items rendered, data is taken from external XML.  In that XML I get an image path, so when I scroll down, the images go out...

Is there a way to prevent the list of items from getting destroyed upon scroll down?

Comment: You should look into what item renderer recycling is in Flex terms as suggested by @f-a below.  Basically Flex only creates as many instances of the renderer as it needs to fill the "view port" of whatever scroller it's using, so if you see 7 and a half things on screen there's probably 9 total instances of the renderer, as you scroll it re-uses these.  Essentially instead of just binding your image url directly you can handle it in set data yourself and build a cache of images, so you can retain recycling and get the images loaded once then instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your list `useVirtualLayout` property to `false`. But beware of performance issues !

See :
http://flexponential.com/2010/01/10/caching-images-loaded-from-a-spark-item-renderer/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe the feature you are talking about is item renderer recycling.

For performance reasons I don't recommend turning this off but if you have to you can set 
`useVirtualLayout="false"` on your list

Comment: Hi men tks for you help, look I tried that but it's not working....I'm using a custom item rendered.... could be that?